# CSS: Displaying/scaling images without messing up the proportions?

Tags: css, image-scaling

I have an image, its 120 x 90 px for example. Now I want to display a smaller version of that image, with 80 x 50 px for example. I know I can use width and height which will work for images having the same size.

Now my problem is that I have different images, which have a different original size and just using a static width and height will make some images look strange (because the proportions are messed up).

How could I handle such cases? Is it possible in pure CSS, or do I need some JS?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201306/how_to_proportionally_scale_images_that_have_dimension_attributes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We call this dynamic divs the image will resize when de div is smaller or bigger.

An example

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}

.video embed,
.video object,
.video iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width:500px;">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cTxYc/) note: if you resize your browser window you see that the image is resized too.

If you make a small div the image is small too. etc.